# In memory realm loses data even though I am calling from same thread

Tags: ios, swift, realm

**NOTE: I have seen other posts but my problem is a little different**

I have a helper class to access Realm. Every function in this class creates it's own instance of the Realm object to avoid thread issues, to be specific `Realm accessed from incorrect thread.`; This works perfectly fine for disk Realm; however, for my in memory realm the data is inserted successfully but when I try to retrieve it I get nothing. I thought maybe Realm is being accessed from different threads so what I did is I created a `DispatchQueue` and I always access realm from that queue.

Here is my code

```
protocol Cachable {}

protocol InMemoryCache {
    func create<T: Cachable>(model: T.Type,
                             _ completion: @escaping (Result<T, Error>) -> ())
    
    func save(object: Cachable,
              _ completion: @escaping (Result<Void, Error>) -> ())
    
    func fetch<T: Cachable>(model: T.Type,
                            predicate: NSPredicate?,
                            sorted: Sorted?,
                            _ completion: @escaping (Result<[T], Error>) -> ())
}
    

enum RealmInMemoryCacheError: Error {
    case notRealmSpecificModel
    case realmIsNil
    case realmError
}


final class RealmInMemoryCache {

    private let configuration: Realm.Configuration
    private let queue: DispatchQueue

    init(_ configuration: Realm.Configuration) {
        self.queue = DispatchQueue(label: "inMemoryRealm", qos: .utility)
        self.configuration = configuration
    }
}

extension RealmInMemoryCache : InMemoryCache{
    func create<T>(model: T.Type,
                   _ completion: @escaping (Result<T, Error>) -> ()) where T : Cachable {
        self.queue.async {
            guard let realm = try? Realm(configuration: self.configuration) else {
                return completion(.failure(RealmInMemoryCacheError.realmIsNil))
            }
            
            guard let model = model as? RealmSwift.Object.Type else {
                return completion(.failure(RealmInMemoryCacheError.notRealmSpecificModel))
            }
        
        
            do {
                try realm.write { () -> () in
                    let newObject = realm.create(model, value: [], update: .all) as! T
                    return completion(.success(newObject))
                }
            } catch {
                return completion(.failure(RealmInMemoryCacheError.realmError))
            }
        }
    }
    
    func save(object: Cachable,
              _ completion: @escaping (Result<Void, Error>) -> ()) {
        self.queue.async {
            guard let realm = try? Realm(configuration: self.configuration) else {
                return completion(.failure(RealmInMemoryCacheError.realmIsNil))
            }
            
            guard let object = object as? RealmSwift.Object else {
                return completion(.failure(RealmInMemoryCacheError.notRealmSpecificModel))
            }
        
        
            do {
                try realm.write { () -> () in
                    realm.add(object, update: .all)
                    return completion(.success(()))
                }
            } catch {
                return completion(.failure(RealmInMemoryCacheError.realmError))
            }
        }
    }
    
    func fetch<T>(model: T.Type,
                  predicate: NSPredicate?,
                  sorted: Sorted?,
                  _ completion: @escaping (Result<[T], Error>) -> ()) where T : Cachable {
        self.queue.async {
            guard let realm = try? Realm(configuration: self.configuration) else {
                return completion(.failure(RealmInMemoryCacheError.realmIsNil))
            }
            
            guard
                let model = model as? RealmSwift.Object.Type else {
                return completion(.failure(RealmInMemoryCacheError.notRealmSpecificModel))
            }
            
            
            var objects = realm.objects(model)
            
            if let predicate = predicate {
                objects = objects.filter(predicate)
            }

            if let sorted = sorted {
                objects = objects.sorted(byKeyPath: sorted.key, ascending: sorted.ascending)
            }

            return completion(.success(objects.compactMap { $0 as? T}))
        }
    }
}

extension Object: Cachable {}

struct Sorted {
    var key: String
    var ascending: Bool = true
}
```

I eliminated code that doesn't add any benefit to the question hence you see empty/missing things in the above code. However, the code above works 100% copied and pasted.

I tried creating realm in the initialized instead so I have a strong reference to it; however, that causes issues with thread safety, it may work for few times but it would at some point crash the app due to the error `Realm accessed from incorrect thread.`

As you may tell, my goal is to make the above code generic and 100% thread safe even if called from a background thread say in a different function. Reason behind it is imagine the above class is an API and different programmers will use it, and sometimes they will call a function on a `background` thread for example without actually knowing what is going under the hood. I do not want the application to crash if they did such a thing.

**EDIT: This is how the helper class is initialized**

```
let realmInMemory = RealmInMemoryCache(Realm.Configuration(inMemoryIdentifier: "globalInMemoryRealm")

// Then I can use it like so (replace model with your realm model)
realmInMemory.create(model) { result in {
   switch result {
      ...
   }
}
```

**EDIT 2: Here is a full example of how the above class works**

```
import RealmSwift

final class MessageRealmEntity: Object {
    @objc dynamic var id: String = ""
    @objc dynamic var message: String = ""

    convenience init(id: String, message: String) {
        self.init()
        self.id = id
        self.message = message
    }
    
    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        "id"
    }
}

// THIS IS NOT PART OF THE PROBLEM, THIS `Main` CLASS IS JUST A DRIVER. THE CODE INSIDE IT COULD RUN ANYWHERE.
final class Main {
    let realmInMemory = RealmInMemoryCache(Realm.Configuration(inMemoryIdentifier: "globalInMemoryRealm"))
    
    func run() {
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
            
            
            let semaphore: DispatchSemaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 0)
            
            var entity = MessageRealmEntity(id: "1", message: "Hello, World!")
            
            self.realmInMemory.save(object: entity) { result in
                switch result {
                case .success(_):
                    print("Saved successfully")
                case .failure(let error):
                    print("Got error")
                }
                semaphore.signal()
            }
            _ = semaphore.wait(wallTimeout: .distantFuture)
            
            
            self.realmInMemory.fetch(model: MessageRealmEntity.self, predicate: nil, sorted: nil) { result in
                switch result {
                case .success(let messages):
                    print(messages.count) // This will return 0 when it should be 1 since we inserted  already
                case .failure(let error):
                    print("Got error")
                }
                
                semaphore.signal()
            }
            
            _ = semaphore.wait(wallTimeout: .distantFuture)
        }
    }
}

let main: Main = Main()
main.run()
```

All other methods are called the same way.

**EDIT3:**

- I opened github issue if anyone is interested to follow it, here is the link: https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/7017 there is a video and more explanation there
- This is a github link to download a project to reproduce the bug https://github.com/Muhand/InMemoryRealm-Bug

Comment: I am not seeing you're setting this up as an [in-memory Realm](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#in-memory-realms). Perhaps you omitted that code? Can you include it so we can see how it's initially configured? You would need something like this `self.inMemRealm = try! Realm(configuration: Realm.Configuration(inMemoryIdentifier: "MyInMemoryRealm"))`

Comment: If you look in the functions it is the 2nd line for example if you look inside `create` function you have `self.queue.async {
            guard let realm = try? Realm(configuration: self.configuration) else {`

Comment: That's doesn't match the code in my comment and isn't an inMemoryIdentifier as far as I can see. e.g. `self.configuration` is not this `inMemoryIdentifier: "MyInMemoryRealm")`

Comment: It is the same but the difference is the configurations are passed on initialization; never the less I have added the helper class initialization by editting my question. And like said realm initialization is done inside every function like I have showing you. Thanks.

Comment: I see., Are you not passing any value here `realmInMemory.create(model)` to realm? e.g. [create(_:value:update:)](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm-sdks/swift/10.4.0/Structs/Realm.html#/s:10RealmSwift0A0V6create_5value6updatexxm_ypAC12UpdatePolicyOtSo0aB6ObjectCRbzlF)

Comment: I edited the question and included more code to show how to use the above class and how I use it myself by creating a simple full example. Note: The above works 100% fine if I use disk, the issue is only with memory. If I set up break points and fetch realm at the moment save was done then everything is good but if I try to `fetch` later then data is missing.

Comment: Is realm going out of scope and deallocating? I see in main theres a `save` and a `fetch` it's a little unclear how those are being used. This `let main: Main = Main()` but then when is save called or fetch? You've got to keep the realm var alive somehow so can you show us how that's done?

Comment: That main class doesn't exist in the real application. It is just a driver to simplify the problem. I am creating a project on github that can be compiled and I will link it to the question.

Comment: @Jay I updated the question and now it has a link to github repository which includes the project to reproduce and also a github issue which shows the actual issue with a video.

Comment: You project won't build for us, but looking over it some basic troubleshooting may reveal additional points. Here `func save(object: Cachable,` did you add a breakpoint and then examine the passed in `object` var, along with what happens here `guard let realm` to ensure that it's actually the Realm you think it is? We use in memory Realms all the time and have not had any issues - that being said, our code is considerably simpler as shown in my comment above; get the in-memory realm class var and write to it.

Comment: Yes I have done that already. Please watch the video on GitHub. The weird part is adding a breakpoint solves the issue. The goal is not just to write a wrapper. It’s a cache protocol so I can change cache libraries whenever I want in the future

Comment: I am still thinking your Realm is being deallocated at some point - that's an explanation that fits the issue. Have you tried adding in `realm.refresh()` to force realm to refresh between run loops?

Comment: I really don't know. I have been thinking about that too but when I placed breakpoints then I started to doubt it. And yes I did try `realm.refresh` but no luck. I will keep this post updated if I find something. I opened an issue on `Github` and let see.

Comment: I was able to solve the issue, you can checkout my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading the [documentation](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/) of Realm again and again and keep thinking of what @Jay have said in the comments, I paid more attention to this quote from the documentation

> Notice: When all in-memory Realm instances with a particular identifier go out of scope with no references, all data in that Realm is deleted. We recommend holding onto a strong reference to any in-memory Realms during your app’s lifetime. (This is not necessary for on-disk Realms.)

Key sentence in the above quote is

> When all in-memory Realm instances with a particular identifier go out of scope with no references, all data in that Realm is deleted.

In other words my `Realm` object is going out of scope everytime I try to save or fetch or do any other function

for example:

```
self.queue.async {
            guard let realm = try? Realm(configuration: self.configuration) else {
                completion(.failure(RealmInMemoryCacheError.realmIsNil))
                return
            }
            
            guard let object = object as? RealmSwift.Object else {
                completion(.failure(RealmInMemoryCacheError.notRealmSpecificModel))
                return
            }
        
        
            do {
                try realm.write { () -> () in
                    realm.add(object, update: .all)
                    completion(.success(()))
                    return
                }
            } catch {
                completion(.failure(RealmInMemoryCacheError.realmError))
                return
            }
        }
```

In the above code Realm goes out of scope as soon as that queue is done with it. Then Realm will look if there is any other variable in memory with the same identifier if so then it does nothing otherwise it will delete the current realm to optimize.

So the solution to the problem is basically to create a strong reference to realm with this identifier and then in each function re-create realm with the same identifier as well to avoid `Realm accessed from incorrect thread` This will however render in an extra variable that is not used but I think that is okay for now, at least it is my solution until something official comes from Realm. Keep in mind the process of re-initializing should not be an overhead since Realm takes care of that optimization.

Here is what I have done

```
final class RealmInMemoryCache {

    private let configuration: Realm.Configuration
    private let queue: DispatchQueue
    private let strongRealm: Realm     <-- Added variable

    init(_ configuration: Realm.Configuration) {
        self.queue = DispatchQueue(label: "inMemoryRealm", qos: .utility)
        self.configuration = configuration
        self.strongRealm = try! Realm(configuration: self.configuration)    <-- Initialized here
    }
}
```

and in other functions I do something like the following

```
...
        self.queue.async {
            guard let realm = try? Realm(configuration: self.configuration) else {
                completion(.failure(RealmInMemoryCacheError.realmIsNil))
                return
            }
...
```

What threw me off thinking my Realm was going out of scope is when I setup breakpoints Realm started behaving perfectly fine. Although I still don't know 100% for sure why but my thinking is that xcode debugger might have created a strong reference to Realm when I write the command `po realm.objects(...)` in `lldb`.

I will accept this answer for now, unless someone has a better solution.